# Using setProperty variables as input to XSL

Tags: jms, apache-camel

I am currently using setHeader variables in an Apache Camel route as input params to an XSL file. This does not work with setProperty variables, however. Is that not supported in Camel?

Thanks!

UPDATE--

Here's my route...

```
<camel:route>
          <camel:from uri="file:/usr/local/jms_support/update"/>
          <camel:convertBodyTo type="String" />
          <camel:multicast>
            <camel:pipeline>
              <camel:bean ref="getPidsForUpdate"/>

                    <camel:setProperty propertyName="work_or_image"><camel:constant>image</camel:constant></camel:setProperty>

                    <camel:setProperty propertyName="pid"><camel:constant>1234</camel:constant></camel:setProperty>
                    <camel:setProperty propertyName="work_pid"><camel:constant>1234</camel:constant></camel:setProperty>
                    <camel:setProperty propertyName="bibid"><camel:constant>1234</camel:constant></camel:setProperty>
            </camel:pipeline>
            <camel:pipeline>
              <camel:to uri="xslt:xsl/test.xsl"/>
              <camel:to uri="file:/usr/local/jms_support/update_test"/>
            </camel:pipeline>
          </camel:multicast>
        </camel:route>
```

Answer (score 1):

What Camel version do you use?

The Xstl components sets the headers and properties as parameters. You can enable TRACE logging on org.apache.camel.builder.xml, and see which parameters is being added.

See the source code for XsltBuilder and the configureTransformer method in the bottom: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/builder/xml/XsltBuilder.java

Comment: Hi Claus, 2.1 is the Camel version.  I'm setting the properties in one pipeline, but they don't seem to be visible in the pipeline below it.  It's my understanding that the properties should be visible throughout the route.  Thanks again.

Comment: I added my Spring DSL code to my original question.  It seems like those properties should be params in the xsl, but they aren't.  They are if I include them in the same pipeline as the XSL, though.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah you are doing it wrong. The multicase will send a copy of the exchange to the 2 pipelines so they are independent. Just remove the multicast, and set the properties before going to the xslt endpoint.

Comment: Thanks, Claus.  I need the multicast because I need the same message to go to each pipeline.  Basically, variables need to be set in the first pipeline that the second pipeline needs.  They both need the same message as input, though.  Maybe there's some EIP pattern that I don't know about that can handle this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up storing the content of the message in a variable and setting the message back to that content after it was changed, like so...

```
<!-- store original content in header variable -->
<camel:setHeader headerName="marc"><camel:simple>${body}</camel:simple></camel:setHeader>
<!-- run some logic, output gets saved as another header variable, message as this point is now that output -->
<camel:bean ref="getPidsForUpdate"/>
<camel:setHeader headerName="pids"><camel:simple>${body}</camel:simple></camel:setHeader>
```

....set a bunch of variables based on that output, and then

```
<!-- get original message to run some more logic-->
<camel:setBody><camel:simple>${headers.marc}</camel:simple></camel:setBody>
```